# discord.py TypeError: on_member_join() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member' error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(ctx, member : discord.member):
    print(f'{time} {member} has joined {ctx.guild.name}, Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}')
    with open('join-log.txt', 'a') as joinlog:
        joinlog.writelines(f'{time} {member} has joined {ctx.guild.name}, Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}\n')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(ctx, member : discord.member):
    print(f'{time} {member} has joined {ctx.guild.name}, Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}')
    with open('leave-log.txt', 'a') as leavelog:
        leavelog.writelines(f'{time} {member} has left {ctx.guild.name}, Server ID: {ctx.guild.id}\n')
```

This code is intended to make a text file and store users that leave and join servers with my bot in it. The error that it is coming up with is

`TypeError: on_member_join() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'`

But I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this code

Comment: `on_member` events just take `member` as an argument, nothing more. `ctx` is just for `commands`, that is why you probably get the error message.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: `on_member_join` and `on_member_remove` just have `member` as an argument, not `ctx, member : discord.member`

Comment: I need ctx though. is there anyway that I can make it so I can?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments: `on_member` events just take `member` as an argument, nothing more.

To still be able to get the `name` of the `guild` or the `id` we can replace `ctx` with `member`. We also request the exact time with `datetime.datetime.utcnow` but you can also do it in any other way.

**Have a look at the full code:**

```py
import datetime

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print(f'{datetime.datetime.utcnow()} {member} has joined {member.guild.name}, Server ID: {member.guild.id}')
    with open('join-log.txt', 'a') as joinlog:
        joinlog.writelines(f'{datetime.datetime.utcnow()} {member} has joined {member.guild.name}, Server ID: {member.guild.id}\n')

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print(f'{datetime.datetime.utcnow()} {member} has left {member.guild.name}, Server ID: {member.guild.id}')
    with open('leave-log.txt', 'a') as leavelog:
        leavelog.writelines(f'{datetime.datetime.utcnow()} {member} has left {member.guild.name}, Server ID: {member.guild.id}\n')
```

**The output:**

```py
2021-05-14 22:56:12.511888 XXXX#0000 has left Test Server, Server ID: XXX
2021-05-14 22:56:22.067174 XXXX#0000 has joined Test Server, Server ID: XXX
```